# Json.NET initialization throws System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nuget

I have a solution with two components:

- A .NET 4.5 console application (`A`).
- A PCL library consuming Newtonsoft's Json.NET (`B`).

As long as only `B` uses and refers to `Json.NET` (as a NuGet package), everything just works fine. But as soon as I add a reference to the very same NuGet package from `A`, I consistently get:

`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.SerializationBinder' ...`

I tracked down the issue to be caused by NuGet including two different versions of the `Json.NET` assembly:

- The one used by `A` has the *File Description* set to **Json.NET**
- The one used by `B` has the *File Description* set to **Json.NET Portable**

Apparently, one assembly cannot be replaced by the other. My PCL no longer finds the version it expects, hence the exception.

How can I configure NuGet so that both projects refer to the same *portable* version of `Json.NET`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround to make sure that both `B` and `A` refer to the same **Json.NET Portable** assembly.

By default, NuGet configured the `<HintPath>` to be set to the `net45` version of the library:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

which is at the root of this conflict. So edit the `A.csproj` file to this instead:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.6\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+aspnetcore50\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

With that in place, the exact same assembly will be used both by `A` and `B`.

Comment: Don't forget to change "targetFramework" in package.config, so other developers will get correct version of lib